# Usage of ていく in 死んでいく

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 世の中結局強い物が勝つ。
>   弱い奴らは死んでいく。
>   ただそれだけ
>
> 弱い奴らは勝手に死んでいくのだ

Maybe a better way of phrasing this question would be asking the difference in using merely plain form and this form.

e.g.

> 強いものが勝ち弱いものは死ぬ
>
> 強いものが生き残り、弱いものは死んでいく

Can someone try to explain the difference in nuance and meaning between them? (And before anyone starts to explain the super basics of ていく I already know and understand them but I'm having trouble understanding it as seen above. I'm not asking for a translation.)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit : Take a look at the comments after reading.**

I think this link will answer pretty well your questions,
[with a nice reflection that helps clarifying the nuances between the different forms.](http://www.cjvlang.com/petitprince/birdheart/dyingj.html)

To sum up :

死ぬ：To be going to die.

死んでいる：To be dead.

**死んでいく：To be dying, with the idea that the process is occuring gradually.**

> ていく also conveys the ideas that what's happening is going away from the speaker, and therefore :
>
> - Is often used with verbs that are related to disapearance : 消えていく...
> - Makes the speaker sound more objective/indifferent.

On the contrary :

> てくる conveys the ideas that what's happening is going toward the speaker, and therefore :
>
> - Is often used with verbs that are related to appearance: 出てくる...
> - Makes the speaker sound more subjective/concerned.

Comment: Interesting website. I am no expert at this (and I am not suggesting the website is wrong about "The little Prince") but I thought it was similar to 買物に行ってくる only instead of "going shopping and coming back" this is "The weak die (and don't comeback)".  I asked where the statement comes from because it sounds like a general statement; "In this world, in the end, the strong win, the weak die." rather than present/future; "In this world, in the end, the strong will win and the weak are slowly dying"(?)

Comment: In addition to Alox's nice answer, 死んでいく can also mean multiple people die one after another.

Comment: To be honnest, I don't fully understand the meaning of ていく, I just thought this website was a pretty good match with the question... I also feel ていく has that "and don't come back" or "once and for all" flavor with verbs that imply disappearance. I wasn't aware of the "one after another" meaning, which would fit perfectly.

"The strongs survive, and the weaks die like flies."

Comment: I read today that てきた can mean continue for a long time so I guess it can apply to ていく aswell.

Comment: @Alox: What conveys "and don't come back" or "once and for all" is ～てしまう. ～ていく and ～てくる has a meaning of gradual change and it can mean accumulation of repetitive occurence when it's applied to a collective thing.

Comment: @user4092: don't てくる and ていく also convey a meaning of movement towards/away from the speaker (either physically or temporally), and hence in the case of dieing, they are going on to somewhere else (and not coming back)?